# how to work with Quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, quotient-group

In this extension $\frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{<6+4x+6x^2+3x^3>}:\mathbb Q$,is this 
$-3x^3=6+4x+6x^2$ true?

Also is this like a general rule?

where can I find specific topics about this? and for example not just working with $\mathbb Q[x]$ but with $\mathbb Z_5[x] $ or another weird rings like the first one?

Apologies for my ignorance in abstract algebra..

Comment: Reducible $\pmod 5,$ as $$ 3(x+1) (x^2 + x + 2) \equiv 3 x^3 + 6 x^2 + 4 x + 6 \pmod 5$$

Comment: Over the rationals you get a field

Comment: Yes. In all quotient rings $R/I$  if the sum of two elements $a,b\in R$ is an element of the ideal $I$, i.e. $a+b\in I$, then the cosets $(a+b)+I$ and $0+I$ are equal, and consequently so are the cosets $a+I$ and $(-b)+I$. This is not unlike saying that $22=-2$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ because $22+2=24$ is an element of the ideal $12\Bbb{Z}$ that was moded out.

Comment: Yes, Annelise, it is a general rule. And any intro abstract algebra text that has a sections on polynomial rings and quotient rings, or on extension fields, should help you. Or just type some of those phrases into Google and see what comes back at you.